# Applescript: the predefined variable "tab" is interpreted literally?

Tags: variables, constants, applescript

According to [AppleScript in a Nutshell](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/applescript-in-a/1565928415/re94.html), `tab` can be used as a predefined variable when creating strings but when I do the result is just the literal string *tab*.

```
set tsv to tsv & "scrolltime:" & tab & "23"
```

gives

[image: tab]

Is O'Reilly wrong or am I missing something obvious?

---

Apple's own reference of [text constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW38) in AppleScript agrees with O'Reilly.

Comment: What is `tsv`. And could it be that the code runs in an (application) tell block which has its own `tab` implementation?

Comment: `tsv` is a string with tab separated values. The code runs in a `tell safari`, `tell document 1` block. `linefeed` works in the same block.

Comment: @vadian You are probably right, Safari obviously has its own tabs.

Comment: Safari has **tab class** and AppleScript has **tab property**. When you put **tab** inside a tell block, the compiler see it as Safari's **tab class**.  Then, if left operand in concatenation is text, the interpreter coerce **implicitly** the class to the text (result is class name "tab", string). This is the reason you got "scrolltime:tab23". Note: every class has text-form name.

Comment: Also, if (generally) there is no equivalent to the conflicting property or constant, and **you still want to use it inside the tell block**, you can tell the interpreter **explicitly** that you want to use it rather than the class. Using the trick: **tell application "Safari" to "scrolltime:" & (run script "«property tab »") & "23"**

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly as I suspected in the comments. Safari defines an own `tab` property with a completely different functionality.

To workaround the problem you have to use `character id 9` inside a Safari `tell` block

```
set tsv to tsv & "scrolltime:" & character id 9  & "23"
```

An alternative – and even very good practice – is to move all code which doesn't use Safari terminology out of the Safari `tell` block

```
tell application "Safari"
    set tsv to name of window 1 
end tell
set tsv to tsv & "scrolltime:" & tab  & "23"
tell application "Safari"
   -- do other Safari stuff
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround would be to define a `reference to` the desired object outside of any tell statement influences, for example:

```
set realTab to a reference to tab -- pipes can also be used to escape an identifier, e.g. |tab|

set tsv to "" -- current string or whatever
tell application "Safari"
   tell document 1
      set tsv to tsv & "scrolltime:" & realTab & "23"
   end tell
end tell
return tsv
```

Answer (score 0):

don't modify the **tab** Applescript variable.

```
set tab to "whatever"
return "scrolltime:" & tab & "23"

> scrolltime:whatever23
```

you can set it back with

```
set tab to ASCII character 9
```

Comment: I have not done that. Just searched my code. Only other occurrence I found was `tell current tab`.

Comment: But your answer makes some sense. Why would it interpret it as a string(variable) when not in quotes?

Comment: `ASCII character` is outdated since macOS 10.5 Leopard (2007).

Comment: And if you create a new script with just this line: `set tsv to "scrolltime:" & tab & "23"`